# Unexpected Rss Link

Tags: vuepress

[I wrote this into config.js themeConfig:{nav:[]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggt5r.png)

but the html it built shows
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKpAh.png)

idk why there's .html after this href

Comment: I think this is a bug of vuepress, filed an issue at [#2292](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/2292)

Comment: thank u for post the issue ,seems tht it cant be solved recently

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Comment: It's solved as i use absolute path